# What is wrong with this search filter code for a webpage search input box?

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage, storage

This gets called on the onkeyup event in my html search bar input.
I walked through it with the debugger and it is actually getting the searchInput that the user types, but something about the filter() function doesn't work. It doesn't actually filter through the storageSvc array and then re-rendering the table with the filtered data. "name" is part of an object in my data array.

No errors, its just not actually filtering the data.

```
function searchTeam(){
    let searchInput = document.getElementById("searchInput").value;
    storageSvc.filter({name:searchInput});
    // re render table 
    renderTable("#tableContainer", storageSvc.list());
}
filter(filterObj) {
    //returns a copy of the filtered array
    ///e.g., storageSvc.filter({coachLicenseLevel:1});
    return this.model.data.filter((d) => {
        for (const key of Object.keys(filterObj)) {
            if (d[key] !== filterObj[key]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `storageSvc`?

Comment: Check the answer by camaulay as it explains the problem with your code. Also, if you intend not to return the filtered results immediately then cache the filtered data in a storageSvc property and return the resulting array when list method is invoked.

Comment: storageSvc = new storageService(teamData, "teamData");

Comment: list() {
      //return the list of data items as is
      return this.model.data;
   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually using the returned value from the filter function.

Try assigning the returned value of the filter function to a variable and then pass that variable to your render fucntion:

```js
function searchTeam() {
  let searchInput = document.getElementById("searchInput").value;
  const filteredResults = storageSvc.filter({ name: searchInput });
  // renderTable("#tableContainer", storageSvc.list() );
  renderTable("#tableContainer", filteredResults);
}

function filter(filterObj) {
  //returns a copy of the filtered array
  ///e.g., storageSvc.filter({coachLicenseLevel:1});
  return this.model.data.filter((d) => {
    for (const key of Object.keys(filterObj)) {
      if (d[key] !== filterObj[key]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  });
}
```